# Что означает операция разыменовывания массива? C++

Tags: c++, массивы, sizeof

Изучая итераторы, наткнулся на такой код:

```
int a1[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};            
int а2[sizeof(a1)/sizeof(*a1)]; // a2 имеет тот же размер, что и a1             
// указывает на следующий элемент после последнего скопированного в а2             
auto ret = copy(begin(a1), end(a1), a2); // копирует a1 в a2
```

Я не понимаю, что означает *a1 во второй строке. Интуитивно я понимаю, что *a1 - это должен быть первый элемент массива, чтобы операторы sizeof после деления вернули количество элементов массива a1. Но что конкретно означает *a1 и как это работает?

Вопрос 2: При создании обычного массива его размер должен быть указан константой времени компиляции. Значит ли это, что sizeof при компиляции неявно подставляет вместо себя результат вычисления размера?

Comment: Наверное пару букв решили сэкономить. Это то же самое, что и `a1[0]` (первый элемент массива) / (чтобы не путать людей обычно подобное выражение записывают с чуть большим количеством букв -- `sizeof(a1) / sizeof(a1[0])`)

Comment: @avp как я и сказал, я это понимаю. Но как это работает? Это же оператор разыменовывания? Я не смог найти ничего по поводу разыменовывания массивов

Comment: Поищите что-то на тему "эквивалентность массивов и указателей" (в сети д.б. много любителей растолковать это) (или K&R почитайте)

Comment: Конструкции `a1[i]` и `*(a1 + i)` полностью эквивалентны. Точно также эквивалентны эти два выражения: `&a1[i]` и `a1 + i`. Т.е., идентификатор массива `a1` без квадратных скобок играет роль указателя на этот массив. Разница лишь в том, что `sizeof(a1)` возвратит размер массива, а не указателя. Таков синтаксис C++ - это нужно больше принять, а не понять))

Comment: @LShadow77 `a1` сам по себе **не** является указателем. Некоторые операции над `a1` неявно преобразуют его в указатель (например `*`, `+` и даже `[]`). `sizeof` нет, но не только он. Еще как минимум `&` и `decltype` не преобразуют. Еще массивом можно инициализировать ссылку на массив (а указателем нет)...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а я и не написал, что это указатель. Я написал, цитирую: "идентификатор массива a1 без квадратных скобок играет роль указателя на этот массив." Играет роль. Эквивалентен. Но не *является*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int a1[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

`a1` - это объект типа массива

`*a1 == * ( & a1 [ 0 ] )`  - язык автоматически преобразовывает массив на указатель к первому элементу. А звёздочка к указателю означает ссылку на элемент массива. Например, записи :

```
* a1 = 10 ;
* ( & a1 [ 0 ] ) = 10 ;
a1 [ 0 ] = 10 ;
```

идентичны.

Функция размер `sizeof` вычисляется в момент компиляции программы. Сначала в массиве подсчитывается фактическое количество элементов. А в ассемблерном коде уже размер всего в массива в байтах *(40 байт) Размер ассемблерного типа **.long** равен четырём байтам*.

```
    .type   a1, @object
    .size   a1, 40
a1:
    .long   0
    .long   1
    .long   2
    .long   3
    .long   4
    .long   5
    .long   6
    .long   7
    .long   8
    .long   9
```

Итого: `sizeof(a1) == 40` , `sizeof(*a1) == 4`.